# select innermost foreach in nested foreach loops with php regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to select innermost foreach loop in nested foreach loops with php regex.

```
{foreach as $key => $value}
    <div>Content</div>

    {foreach as $anotherKey => $anotherValue}
        <div>Test content</div>
        <p>Test Another Content</p>

        {foreach as $k => $v}
            <p> I want to this area </p>
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

I'm using the following regex for single foreach area, this is working. But it isn't enough for nested foreach.

```
/{foreach (\$\w+) as (\$\w+) => (\$\w+)}(.*?){\/foreach}/ms
```

Comment: This is exactly the wrong use for regular expressions. Exactly the same reason as the famous "don't parse html with regular expressions" answer.

Comment: following @JonathanKuhn's comment above, you might consider converting your custom foreach tags to equivalent xml tags easily enough, then process the whole thing as xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `.*?` with `[^{]*+(?:{(?!\/?foreach)[^{]*)*+` to prevent "foreach tags" to be matched between other foreach tags.

result:

```
/{foreach (\$\w+) as (\$\w+) => (\$\w+)}([^{]*+(?:{(?!\/?foreach)[^{]*)*+){\/foreach}/
```

You don't need the m or the s modifier.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU5jI0/1)

details:

```
[^{]*+              # all that is not a {
(?:                 # open a non capturing group
    {(?!\/?foreach) # a { not followed by "foreach" or "/foreach"
    [^{]*                
)*+                 # repeat the group
```

Comment: Casimir thank you. This is working. How is the opposite method? So, select outhermost Foreach?

Comment: @heisenberq: With a recursion: https://regex101.com/r/yU5jI0/2 where `(?R)` stands for the whole pattern.